# How To Find Duplicate Records from Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to highlight those records that are duplicate in Kendo UI Grid

```
var onDataBound = function(e) {
  var nodelist = e.sender.dataSource._data;
  for (var i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
    var tr = nodelist[i];
    // var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');
    // if (tr == e.sender.dataSource._data) return tr;
    // var ff = []; ff = tr; 
  };
}
```

[What I've tried so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779318/how-to-find-duplicate-records-from-kendo-ui-grid#comment72672949_42779318):

```
var onDataBound = function (e) { 
    var nodelist = e.sender.dataSource._data; 

    for (var i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) { 
        var tr = nodelist[i]; 
        // var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('td'); 

        if (tr == e.sender.dataSource._data) 
            return tr; 

        var ff = []; 
        ff = tr; 
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far if i may ask?

Comment: i want to find duplicate records from kendo grid

Comment: Add what you have tried so far

Comment: Yes i can read that, but you haven't showed us what you have tried or where your error is. You should know that SO is not a "Code it for me" site

Comment: var onDataBound = function (e) {
        var nodelist = e.sender.dataSource._data;
        for (var i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
            var tr = nodelist[i];
           // var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');
            if (tr == e.sender.dataSource._data)
                return tr;
            var ff = [];
            ff = tr;
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specified how you want to check for duply, so I did a little function to check all rows and all columns for duplicity. It seem more complex than it really is:

```
var checkGridDuplictyValue = function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        data = grid.dataItems(),
        fields = grid.options.columns.map(x => x.field),
        checkData = {};

    // Gathering data
    data.forEach(d => {
        fields.forEach(f => {  
            if (!checkData.hasOwnProperty(f)) checkData[f] = {};
            if (!checkData[f].hasOwnProperty(d[f])) checkData[f][d[f]] = [];

            checkData[f][d[f]].push(d.uid);
        });
    });

    // Checking for duplicity and styling duplicated rows
    Object.keys(checkData).forEach(k => {
        Object.keys(checkData[k]).forEach(c => {
            if (checkData[k][c].length > 1) {
                checkData[k][c].forEach(x => $(grid.tbody).find('tr[data-uid="' + x + '"]').addClass("duply-row"));
            }
        });
    });
};
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IhuLE).

It gathers data across all - attention to this point - **visible rows** and adds it in an object which basically is `property=column's value` and `value=array of row's uid`. So it knows how many(and which ones) rows have the same value for the same columns. Then it just loop trough it adding a class to each duplicated row.

Comment: Thanks dear for helping :)